# accessing secure element in galaxy S3

Tags: android, amazon-s3, galaxy, open-mobile-api, secure-element

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 phone. What i wanted to achieve is, I wanted to access the SIM card or the secure element inside galaxy S3.
 I have few questions here:-

1. How do we install applets on a commercial sim card?
2. is the secure element inside galaxy s3, accessible?

Some links i referred, with no real success
https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/UsingSmartCardAPI
http://www.usmile.at/blog/seek-galaxys3

[Javacard applet RPDU does not contain any data when accessed from seek-for-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982327/javacard-applet-rpdu-does-not-contain-any-data-when-accessed-from-seek-for-andro/25990289#25990289)

@vojta kindly please help

EDIT: i have solved the issue. It cannot be dont on a commercial sim. But you need to smart card whose key one knows
Please respond,
Thanks

Comment: Do you have ARA installed on your SIM/Secure element?Otherwise you will not be able to send commands via android to SIM/SE.

Comment: Thats what my question is, how do i install ARA on commercial sim card? If not, where can i find a developer sim?

Comment: You can only install applet on commercial cards if you know the security keys....if you have .cap then you can give it a try with android simulator using http://jcardsim.org/docs/quick-start-guide-simulator-api

Comment: no its no way that i can get the security keys, from where can i get a developer sim?? @AnuragSharma